# Android Filter data in listivew from ActionBar using SearchView

Tags: android, listview, searchview, android-filter

I'm trying to filter the data on the listview using the searchview widget but is not wroking, i can write any query and it does not filter anything.

This is the code i'm using:

```
public class ConectadosActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnQueryTextListener {

ListView listview;
    ListConectadosAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista_conectados);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        session.checkLogin();
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listado_conectados);
        listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        HashMap<String, String> usuario = session.getUserDetails();

        usuarioID = usuario.get(SessionManager.KEY_USER_ID);

        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

            MostrarAlert(ConectadosActivity.this,
                    "No se ha podido cargar la lista de contactos",
                    "Reintentar", "Salir", true, 1);
        }
        new Conectados().execute();
    }

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contactos, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
                .getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        //searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Buscar nombre de contacto");

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // this is your adapter that will be filtered
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            listview.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            listview.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

But as i said is not doing nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, here is a sample app for filtering using `SearchView`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/SearchView

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i've already tried that but i'm populating the listview with an asynctask and the listview is not getting updated after the query in the searchview widget.